# Symmetry factor of tree diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

In [Mark Srednicki's Quantum field theory](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf)(page 89) it says

> This is a general result for *tree diagrams* (those with no closed loops):
>   once the sources have been stripped oﬀ and the endpoints labeled, each
>   diagram with a distinct endpoint labeling has an overall symmetry factor
>   of one. The tree diagrams for a given process represent the lowest-order (in
>   g) nonzero contribution to that process.

So the question is why the symmetry factor of the tree diagram is one with each endpoint labeled? Could you kindly provided a proof or some links including the proof?